# Fastest way to read a very large pdf file as byte array and view in in ASP.NET Web Forms 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms

I need to display a pdf file in an ASP.NET Web Forms 4 application through an ascx user control. I'm using the below code for reading the pdf file as byte array and then write the byte array to the Response directly.

```
var pdfBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
context.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
```

In case of very large pdf files it's not performing well even though the pdf files were generated with Fast Web View option enabled. Can someone suggest a better solution for this?

Comment: Use TransmitFile instead, though be aware the process is asynchronous so deleting/moving/editing the file afterwards get more involved https://stackoverflow.com/q/2187252/529282

Comment: @Martheen I tried with TransmitFile but in the performance analysis it's still not satisfying as the pdf file size is almost 1GB.

Comment: Uh, if you try telling your browser to open that 1 GB file directly, is there a large performance margin compared to opening it through the web app? Maybe open it through an FTP if you want to simulate the network traffic too

Comment: Also, explain what's this "performance" analysis means. Unacceptable usage of RAM? CPU? IO?

Comment: Maybe Adobe View SDK? https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/pdf-embed.html